# WPF UI Automation finding image

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ui-automation, inspect

Hey all i am trying to get an image from a WPF application:

[image]

As you can see the image is under the tree

"Remote phone" window > "" custom > "" image

I've found examples of how to find a textbox and button (and also invoking the button) but i have not yet found code that will allow me to get an image and display it within my form picturebox.

```
LogMessage("Getting RootElement...");
AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.RootElement;

if (rootElement != null)
{
    LogMessage("OK." + Environment.NewLine);

    Automation.Condition condition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Remote phone");

    LogMessage("Searching for Remote Phone Window...");
    AutomationElement appElement = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, condition);

    if (appElement != null)
    {
        LogMessage("OK " + Environment.NewLine);
        LogMessage("Searching for Image...");

        AutomationElement txtElementA = GetTextElement(appElement, "image");

        if (txtElementA != null)
          etc..etc...
```

It finds the **appElement** just fine but once it gets to the **txtElementA** it's *NULL* which it should be since its looking for a **GetTextElement** instead of a picture/image element.

What would be the proper code in finding the image and grabbing it and then displaying it within a picturebox on my form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no UI Automation pattern that supports what you're trying to do.  If you look at your inspect window, you'll notice that all of the `IsXXXPatternAvailable` properties are false, which means that none of the patterns are available (except for IsLegacyIAccessblePatternAvailable, but that doesn't help you either).